# Sql get domain name only

Tags: mysql, sql

from ===> to

```
https://www.google.com/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://google.com/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://google.comasd/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://www.google.be/dddasdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://www.google.tr/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://www.google.as/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://www.google.ur/asdkasjdhask  ===> google
https://www.bing.com/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://bing.com/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://bing.comasd/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://www.bing.be/dddasdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://www.bing.tr/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://www.bing.as/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
https://www.bing.ur/asdkasjdhask  ===> bing
```

and the count 
example 7 from google, 6 from bing , 2 from youtube etc.

i tried `SELECT count(*) .......` didn't work how i wanted

Mysql

Comment: how is count() supposed to do string manipulation?

Comment: Be wary of things like `google.co.uk` or `accounts.google.com` here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract domain by using text functions:

```
SELECT LEFT(c, INSTR(c, '.')-1) AS site, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(url,'https://', ''), 'www.', '') AS c
     FROM tab) sub
GROUP BY LEFT(c, INSTR(c, '.')-1);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=281915a030c30bf3e393a6e4f73dd253)**

Comment: This will fail for (for example) `http://test.github.io/` or `http://http://stackoverflow.co.uk/`, also `https://accounts.google.com` and `https://accounts.google.co.hk`. You will need to take the https://publicsuffix.org/ into account to determine the "domain name" from a fqdn.